# Looking for a Set generator

Tags: elementary-set-theory, computational-complexity

English is not my native language.

Hello everybody.

If I have a finite set of natural numbers. It is always possible to find an algorithm that generates it (and of course not the trivial one that only repeat each number of the set) , or could exist a set that is not possible to generate?

Thank you

Comment: What do you mean by trivial? Is it okay to let $A\subseteq \mathbb{N}$ be your set, let $B$ be the set whose elements are the successor elements of $A$. And write your algorithm as "for every $x\in B$, output $x-1$?"

Comment: It's very hard to define "all algorithms other than (some really simple algorithm)" in a way that makes mathematical sense.

Comment: For example, every finite set $A$ of natural numbers can be encoded as $n_A=\sum_{i\in A} 2^i$, and we can write an algorithm which takes any $n$ and returns an $A$ such that $n_A=n$.

Comment: By trivial I think I mean an algorithm with the same size; an algorithm that uses the set B (the succesors) is for me trivial...I'm wondering if it is always possible to find an smaller algorithm that the initial set itself.

Comment: Willie, Thomas. Thank you very much for your interest.

Answer (score 4):

What you're asking appears essentially to be a question of [Kolmogorov complexity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov_complexity), in which case the answer is that the majority of such sets cannot be generated by an algorithm better than the trivial one. This is easily shown by a counting argument in the case of arbitrary sequences of bits; your sets can be transformed into arbitrary sequences of bits by sorting them to get sequences and then difference-encoding the sequences.

Comment: Ok, thank you, Peter.